# A question on Right half-open Interval topology

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Is Right half-open interval topology the same as [Sorgenfrey line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_line)? I think it is, however I am not sure.

Comment: I’ve never seen the term used, but my first guess would be that it’s either the Sorgenfrey line or, more generally, a term for the Sorgenfrey topology on an arbitrary linear order.

Comment: Of course, now the question is a bit weird since the linked Wikipedia article appears to also be the answer.

Comment: It would really help if you mentioned where you encountered this notion.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: this notation is mentioned in the book: Counterexamples_in_Topology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was basically answered in comments, so I am posting a CW-answer, so that the question is [not left unanswered](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-should-one-do-when-ones-question-has-been-answered-in-the-comments).

As the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_line) suggests, the names Sorgenfrey line, lower limit topology and right half-open interval topology are used for the same topological space.

You have mentioned [in a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308063/a-question-on-right-half-open-interval-topology#comment668255_308063) that you have seen this term in the book [Counterexamples in Topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology) - you can check that the definition given in the book is indeed the same as the one given on Wikipedia.